# Python function prints a none value that I have no idea about it's origin

Tags: python, function, printing, console

I have created a function here which prints if a number is prime or not . At the bottom of the image, I tried to print all the numbers in the console to show how many of them are prime numbers. Though all of the number from 2 to 19 showed in the console ,some extra none value attached to every single one of them . I have no clue why these none values appeared with every single number. Can anyone help with that?
( I am using sublime text)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRxFl.png)

Comment: On line 13, you don't need  print(), call prime_numb() directly. As this function doesn't return anything. So print(prime_numb(f)) function showing None at Terminal window

Comment: You are printing it. Perhaps you should just not print it:

Comment: please add code to question in the format:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Your python function will return None if it doesn't end with a return statement, and that's why at the end of every iteration in your for loop, it prints 'None' when it's done running the codes within the prime_numb function. You can fix it by returning a value.